# Close reason not shown?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/191750/) has been migrated from StackOverflow - and apparently back. Both sites show the question as closed, but the close reason is not displayed anywhere.

[image: Question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that is was migrated back to SO, but this normally shouldn't happen, so it's displaying the first migration rather than the most recent one

Comment: It was. I forgot to remove the migration history before moving it back to SO. Unfortunately once migrated I can't revert it.