# How to check what the close reason is?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

**Situation**

I just asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/785851/how-to-search-for-all-excel-files-in-a-folder-with-value-x-right-next-to-value-y) and someone voted to close it.

**Question**

How do I find out what the reason was?

**Research**

I saw somewhere (see [screenshot in this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7078/i-cant-change-my-vote-to-close-bug)) that when voting to close one has to select a reason. Shouldn't I be able to see that reason somewhere even before the question is really closed? How else can I improve my question?

[Close reason not shown?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1493/close-reason-not-shown): My question isn't closed yet. There is just one vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the close option & you'll see the reason being highlighted

Comment: Worked. Suggestion: perhaps the reason should be shown in the tooltip. I wouldn't have clicked on the "close (1)" button to see the reason, I would have clicked on it to cast another vote.

Comment: @Lernkurve Each vote can have its own reason. A single closed question could be for up to five different selected reasons.